# JavaScript static analyser that catches non-existing property names

Tags: javascript, node.js, build, static-analysis

Say, I have a React component like this:

```
var Wizard = React.createClass({

  planAllowsConfigType: function(configType) {
    return true;  
  },

  render: function()
  {
    // Note type in planAlowsConfigType
    var output = this.planAlowsConfigType() ? "Yup, you're good." : "No, sorry!";

    return <div>
            {output}
           </div>;
  }
});
```

Is there a JavaScript static analysis tool that can catch that kind of typo (`this.planAlowsConfigType`) that I can run as part of my build?

*Update*: WebStorm is able to catch some of these but I'm not sure if it's using something proprietary.

Comment: Somebody asked a very similar question to this (essentially the same question) a few days ago, and I don't think it got any answers.

Comment: Atom has eslint plugins which highlight unused and undefined values - https://atom.io/packages/eslint

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, eslint cannot do that for properties, it can for variables, though.

Comment: Your best bet might be TypeScript then, It does in fact catch these errors with the initial ts -> js.